# Unknown Android notification message. Updating Data

Tags: notifications, nexus

This morning my Project Fi Nexus 6P with Android 6.0.1 had an animated icon in the notification list with a progress bar and the text "Updating Data".

Using the search features I didn't find anything that explained what it was.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Can you check your app drawer for an app with a similar icon? If not found there, *Settings › Apps* might have it at least.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Once I zoomed in on the icon I could see it clearly enough to find a match.  It was a Yellowstone app I had downloaded a few months ago.  https://goo.gl/photos/H55YTqfJabp8uiB17

Comment: You might want to [answer your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Comment: Indeed. But please avoid link shorteners here :)

Comment: Will try to fix the short link. I was posting from my phone and just used the link the app generated.

Answer (score 0):

Zooming in to the icon helped identify the app as a Yellowstone guide app.

https://goo.gl/photos/H55YTqfJabp8uiB17

Comment: You can also long-press notifications to see what app caused them.